# JavaScript Chart Library with Multiple X and Y Axes, and Negative Axis Values

Tags: javascript, charts, asp.net-charts

I've played with Google Charts, and a few other java script charting packages, and I have not been able to achieve the desired results.  I'm wondering if anyone would be able to point me toward a JavaScript plotting package, open source or commercial, that they *know* is capable of creating the following type of charts that we are currently creating with the .Net chart control.

Notice the negative axes...
[image: XY Scatter Plot connected with lines .Net Chart Control]

[image]

Here we have multiple X, Y axes.

[image]

Here we have time axes that it'd be nice to zoom on...

We are looking for a JavaScript charting library that can handle charts of this complexity, while still being somewhat simple to configure and use...  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: I think this was a great question. Can't believe it's been officially categorized as "not constructive". Moderators should be mature and swing their axe carefully.

Comment: I ended up using Flot, mostly because it's free :)  It's fairly easy to use, has lots of plugins.  Also, Google Charts has come a long way from when this question was asked, and now basically does everything I want!

Answer (score 4):

I've used http://www.highcharts.com/ - it's a great lib with very easy way to quickly draw something nice. But there are other good options for your needs:

- http://dygraphs.com/
- http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Btw, this is a more 'simple' solution but works great with jQuery: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with

Comment: another one to look at is - amcharts.com